# It is wanted to create an e-mail password.It should have the following properties :

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, solution-verification

When I glimpse on my old combinatorics book , I saw a question. It seems very trivial and I still think like that, but the answer is different from what I expected.

Question: It is wanted to create an e-mail password. It should have the following properties :

$1-)$ It will consist of six characters

$2-)$ It will have three digits ($10$ possibilities) and three letters ($26$ possibilities)

My answer : $10^3 \times 26^3 \times \frac{6!}{3! \times 3!}$   ,

( $\frac{6!}{3! \times 3!}$ means the arrangements among letters and digits.)

Answer of book : $10^3 \times 26^3 $

The book does not mention about any other restriction.I thought that we should arrange the letters and digits as well. However, the book ignores it.

I have never encounter wrong answer in this book before. Am I missing something in this question?

Comment: Your answer is correct according to your posted question.

Comment: Never use such a short password! Use a password manager like Bitwarden and $16$-character or more passwords!

Comment: Might be worth quoting exactly from the book - from what you've said, the book is just straight up incorrect, but maybe there's some nuance that makes it different.